# Display data from a jQuery get() call?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to preform a GET request on a website and display the info I get back. I've checked the website with postman to confirm the URL.

I don't understand what the data looks like when it is returned by the $.get() call. I was hoping a console.log() would display anything as a starting point.

Here's my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(getData);
    //start function calls getData method

function getData(){
    $.get("http://briank1.sgedu.site/leadtracker/api/leads/", gotData, "jsonp");
    //request to get data from URL speficied
    //then pass that info to gotData method
}

function gotData(data){
    console.log(data);
    //print to screen data received from getData method.
}
```

And my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src = "getData.js" async defer></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "getData.css" /> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you just trying to see your response?

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("http://briank1.sgedu.site/leadtracker/api/leads/", function(response) {
            console.log('response: ', response);
         });
        });
```